# getSupportActionBar error (already tried importing the correct imports and extending to appcompat and fragmentactivity

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am trying to make a viewpager slider and I keep running into this error. 
Here is the code of my MainActivity Below

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ViewPager vp;
private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
//actionbar is the deprecated version of the toolbar

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    getSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    //Action Bar
    //ab = getActionBar();
    //ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    //ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    //ViewPager
    vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    vp.setAdapter(new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabs.setViewPager(vp);
}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have already looked through stackoverflow, and I have tried to have MainActivity extend AppcompatActivity, and I have tried having it extend Activity as well as fragmentactivity, as I am using numerous fragments in my viewpager. 
The error keeps occuring at 
     getSupportActionBar();
is there a way to apply both FragmentAcitivty and have it also extend Appcompat? Is this the problem? if not what is?

Comment: Extend to `AppCompatActivity` and call `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)`. If you have your own `Toolbar`, make sure to use a `Theme` that has no `ActionBar` of its own.

Comment: What is 'getSupportActionBar error'? Please add some logcat or error line

Comment: the method `getSupportActionBar(Toolbar);` does not exist. You will never make that work anywhere. You can `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)` OR `ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBat()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);` instead `getSupportActionBar(mToolbar);` before using `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way , first set `toolbar` using `setSupportActionBar` :

```
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
 if (mToolbar != null) {

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar );
        mToolbar .setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }
```

and extend your `class` with `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: What is `toolbar`? Wont that always be null? Shouldnt be `mToolbar`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows yes mToolbar in your code  and toolbar in my code are just  reference objects of Toolbar, I have edited my answer check it now

Comment: If `mToolbar` is not null, you are going to initialize the view again? Toolbar should never be null. Init one time, then set the toolbar last.

Comment: sorry it was mistake , i typed my answer wrongly thanks to be so nice to remind my mistake

Answer (score 0):

first "setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)"